# WordPress - Slider Revolution - Limit max slides per screen size

Tags: wordpress, web, carousel, revolution-slider

Been working on Slider Revolution 6 for over 2days now.

What I need to happen is that:

For dekstop view: 3 max slide show be visible
For tablet view /medium screen/: 2 max slide should be visible
For mobile view: 1 slide should only be visible

can anyone help me with this please? thank you!

Be able to display 2 slides on tablet view

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.